# Disputed bad audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6708843

the proposed answer wasn't in great shape, but I think this does answer the question.

the poster is saying that by passing the URL in the above fashion does render the page without the signin button, which was the question.

I would have added that as a comment, but can't so that at this point in the review process, and I went to upvote and get flagged.

I understand that this was an audit (which I disputing), but this reasonable answer was nixed....

Is there a process to handle something like this?

**Edit**:  Not only was the proposed  answer **correct**, and **verified** by me,  but it was **accepted** (as reposted) and **upvoted**.

Comment: His answer was Correct,  His english was bad. I have answered the original question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975492/remove-sign-in-button-in-google-docs-webview-in-android/27908545#27908545 with his solution that I have validated.  He should get the credit.  I should get some of these negative votes removed.

Comment: @gnat, you cant "help" a new user during the this point in the review process.  up/down/skip are the only options.  I didn't click no action needed.  It was the right answer.

Comment: @StuartSiegler you can comment (if you *can't* comment it means its an audit).  You can edit (inline the two images rather than have them be raw links).  You can ask for clarification about "did this solve the problem or are you asking a new one?" You could down vote for "this isn't useful" (the criteria for a down vote is not "this is not an answer" but rather its usefulness).  Any of these would have had you realize the audit nature, or pass it.

Comment: @MichaelT, or, as it was easy for me to test, I could verify it it was correct. And knowing that it was a first-time answer, **update** the correct answer.

Comment: @StuartSiegler Late answer and first posts are *not* about "is this correct".  Late answer says "This is a new user's answer to an old question. Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam." and "Edit to improve the answer's appearance, clarity, or accuracy" - nothing there says *anything* about correct. It says *everything* about helping a new user learn about the site. This means edit. It means comment. It means help someone who may not understand how to write correct english and use markdown correctly. It means inline the images for them. It means help improve the answer. Not "no action".

Comment: @MichaelT: *Watch for hidden gems* ... like a right answer?  The suggestion is to upvote them. I did.  You guys are wrong here. Downvote away.  I helped someone by reposting an answer that "you" disregarded -- and deleted.

Comment: @StuartSiegler If this is a gem, it needs to be edited, *badly*. You didn't do that.

Answer (score 8):

The whole issue with the post that you reviewed is that **it isn't even an answer**.

[image: review pic]

It is a person asking for more help as an answer - a new user who doesn't understand that new questions must be asked on a separate thread. 
All the user says is "I tried this . . . but it didn't work as I intended", and they are asking for "updates about hide Sign In button?". I'm not seeing an answer to the question anywhere. This is a fairly clear audit.

To answer your second question about what can be done about bad audit - audits are chosen based on their stats, like downvotes and flags. If you think that a certain post shouldn't be an audit, you can open the post outside of the review queue and vote the *opposite* way on it - a post that has -5 and +5 votes won't be chosen for an audit. However, in this case, I absolutely disagree with you; this post isn't really a borderline case. It is very clearly a low quality post, as it isn't even an answer.

Comment: It was an answer.  The question asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975492/remove-sign-in-button-in-google-docs-webview-in-android) by was "Remove sign in button in google docs webview in android"  The Proposed answer, poorly worded answer was use this url: "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="  ...  the way I read it, the poster was saying "You still dont have an answer about your question?"  I have tried this, and it works.....  here's my proof"  That is a valid answer.

Comment: @StuartSiegler Well, the "Thank you" at the end hints that the user is looking for a response. Also, the post is just such low quality, even if it were meant to be an answer, which I still think it wasn't, it should be discarded just for that.

Comment: His answer was Correct, His english was bad.  I have answered the original question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975492/remove-sign-in-button-in-google-docs-webview-in-android/27908545#27908545 with his solution that I have validated.  He should get the credit.  I should get some of these negative votes removed.

Comment: @StuartSiegler if his english was bad, why didn't you fix it with an edit? Why did you either up vote or click "no action"?

Comment: @MichaelT,  You cant in an audit (or at least with the rep I had).

Comment: @StuartSiegler at which point you say "ahh, audit. Is this a known good example with +7 score and no down votes? Or a known bad that was deleted. If I'm not sure if, I'll go look..." And pass the audit.